# R. Shlomo Klonitsky-Kline's dictionary of synonyms and homonyms

Tags: jewish-books, hebrew, rabbis, internet, dictionary

According to the [Hebrew Wikipedia article on R. Shlomo Klonitsky-Kline](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A7%D7%99_(%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F)#%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%93_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F) it is said that he composed a dictionary of Hebrew synonyms and homonyms titled מלון דקדוקי (CMIIW, all of them related to Torah words).

Anyone know where I can find it online either to buy or something?

Comment: Isn't it the book מלון דקדוקי described right there in the entry?

Comment: @Harel13, Tnx! I edited this into the question, leaving the last part. Is it online somewhere?